# "Sphinx cannot be found on your system." when running "rake ts:index"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm setting up a new machine (OS X 10.6.7) to run a Rails app which uses ThinkingSphinx. I have followed the installation instructions, but I'm still getting the following:

```
$ rake ts:index
(in /Users/robert/Projects/Office/code/office)
sh: line 1:  7050 Trace/BPT trap          indexer 2>&1
sh: line 1:  7053 Trace/BPT trap          indexer 2>&1

Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name

For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html
sh: line 1:  7055 Trace/BPT trap          indexer 2>&1
Generating Configuration to /Users/robert/Projects/Office/code/office/config/development.sphinx.conf
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/indexer
  Reason: image not found
```

I read [here](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/installing_sphinx.html) to run the following:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Not sure if this helps, but some more info:

```
$ cd /usr/local/mysql/lib
$ ls
lib                        libmysqlclient_r.dylib
libmysqlclient.18.dylib    libmysqld-debug.a
libmysqlclient.a           libmysqld.a
libmysqlclient.dylib       libmysqlservices.a
libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib  mysql
libmysqlclient_r.a         plugin
```

And from my config/sphinx.yml:

```
development:
  port: 9312
  enable_star: true
  min_prefix_len: 2
  html_strip: true
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
production:
  port: 9312
  enable_star: true
  min_prefix_len: 2
  html_strip: true
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sphinx indexing engine consists of a few binaries, for example for indexing, it uses an executable called "indexer". Try to set the values in config/sphinx.yml to the path where you installed sphinx, as suggested in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I find where Sphinx has been installed?

Comment: PS. I downloaded it from http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/, extracted it, did "$ cd Downloads/sphinx-0.9.9", and then proceeded with "$ ./configure" and so on. However, do I have to specify where the libraries are to be installed during any of this?

Comment: you can try ´which indexer´ or if you get no results, do a `find / -name "indexer"`, which will probably take some time.

Comment: I added the contents of my config/sphinx.yml to the end of my OP. How can I determine if these are the correct settings for my setup? Running "$ which indexer" gives "/usr/local/bin/indexer". It appears that the libmysqlclient.18.dylib library is not being loaded in the original error.

Comment: I am sorry, I overlooked the missing mysql lib message. Your installation of sphinx went through without errors? If it has, check out this page: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=6835, it seems your library needs renaming.

Comment: Hmm. I tried "$ sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/bin/indexer" (substituting 18 for 16), but it's still showing the original error. When I installed Sphinx the first time I used "$ ./configure" instead of "$ LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ./configure --with-mysql-libs=/usr/local/mysql/lib" (like shown in the last link you sent). When installing it again, the "$ make" and "$ sudo make install" commands didn't really output much, so I'm thinking I may need to totally uninstall Sphinx and start over? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Before you do, try LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib rake ts:index

Comment: @mosch, I had already uninstalled it before seeing your reply, however, I've got it working now. I believe it was an issue with MySQL 5.5 (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61243). I ended up uninstalling MySQL 5.5 and installed v5.1.57 instead. After reinstalling Sphinx it seems to be working. Thank you for your help over the last day!

Answer (score 2):

The error is thrown when loading the executables. For some reason the dynamic loader can't find the MySQL libraries. I've seen this happen a number of times with recent MySQL releases.

You can change the search path of the MySQL library in the binaries so the loader will load them from a specific location like this:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/bin/indexer
```

You will need to do the same for all the other Sphinx binaries (like searchd).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these problems occurred if you have installed the sphinx engine before installing the mysql.

In that case, you need to uninstall the sphinx and install it with the following command in macosx.

```
brew install sphinx --with-mysql
```

Once you done that, the reference problem will be solved.