# error on starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error on starting the rails server.

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name


For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html

script/rails: No such file or directory - uname -p
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/mi
me_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant MOBILE
Exiting
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.
rb:44:in `connect': Unknown MySQL server host 'to appmallstaging.cxc6soormw9j.us
-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (0) (Mysql2::Error)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/m
ysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_conne
ction'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) i
n checkout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout'

        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connectio
n'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_
connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connectio
n'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_r
ecord/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__777791075__prepare__723499589__callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dis
patch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dis
patch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/applic
ation/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initia
lizable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/applic
ation.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railti
e/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config/environment.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'

        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_
support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:
51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:
51:in `initialize'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from D:/ROR/appmallserver/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:
40:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:
40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:2
00:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/comman
ds/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:3
01:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:2
52:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/comman
ds/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:21:in `require'
        from script/rails:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is this in a rails project not made by you?. It is using Thinking Sphinx for searching. You'll have to install Thinking Sphinx or remove it for initializers or config files

Comment: i have installed the thinking sphynx gem.but then aslo the error persists

Answer (score 0):

Look into the link below and follow the instructions:

http://pat.github.com/ts/en/quickstart.html

Hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I started this as a comment, but it got to long.

You have to set it up correctly. The Thinking Sphynx gem is dependent on the Sphynx library, witch you also have to install, [instuctions](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/installing_sphinx.html). This seems to be you problem now, but you'll have to do more to make it work.

You must have MySQL and/or PostgreSQL, you cannot use SQLite.

Follow VenkatK's link and learn how to do it. There is also a railscasts episode [120-thinking-sphinx](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx) if you are a pro member on railscasts there is a revised episode [120-thinking-sphinx-revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx-revised)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message show, problem is with your configuration for sure. Reinstalling the spinx may help you in your case.

Following is the similar one,

["Sphinx cannot be found on your system." when running "rake ts:index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190435/sphinx-cannot-be-found-on-your-system-when-running-rake-tsindex)